# PoE solution for multi adapters

Tags: power-over-ethernet, ubiquiti

Currently, we are implementing around 20 Ubiquiti P2P units and I am wondering if there is any solution for replacing the original power injectors with any other easy to manage and arranged devices. I can't imagine that I have to use all of the 20 adapters inside my data center which means 20 wall plugs. 
If the best practice says that I have to use the original injectors instead of searching for an alternative solution please advice about keeping all of them inside one locker or cabinet or any other better idea.
* I can't use outside EdgePoint S16 unit since I need to drop all of the 20 cables from external unit to my datacenter and connect them to core switch for VLANS purposes.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking. I do not even see a question mark anywhere in your question. Are you asking if we can recommend a solution?

Comment: Yes! recommend a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic for SE sites, except [softwarerecs.se] and [hardwarerecs.se].

Comment: Provided that Ubiquiti units support standard IEEE PoE, you can just use a PoE switch.

Comment: I found no standard POE for any of Ubiquiti's point-to-point units' datasheets.  They use so-called "passive POE", ie non-standard "power over twisted pair" on 4+5/7+8 at 24V.  Search for "passive poe midspan injector multiport" and you'll find things alleged to work, but obviously if you're outside standards and not using the manufacturer's parts you're on your own when things go wrong.  This doesn't mean it won't work, it means you won't get much help if it doesn't.

Comment: Which model of point-to-point units do you have?